# Magento2 Certain Mobile Product Page Images too big - not responsive

Tags: magento2, mobile

I have having an issue with some product pages. The images are too big causing the entire page not to be responsive. It only happens with some product pages, not all. All product pages use 1200x1200 sized images, and are setup exactly the same way.

All other pages on the website (home, category) are responsive and look great on mobile. But some of the product pages, the images are too big, causing the rest of the page to lose its responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to fix it was to use the AMP version only on mobile always, and that fixed the issue.

But Im not sure if the original issue was Magento specific, because my other magento website works perfectly on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that this is an issue that is commented, I don't know if it is connected to the original reported issue, but I happens for all of our staging/development/production sites we have. It doesn't seem to only be product images, but also images that are coming from third-party modules to in the pub/media folder.

Edit:

OK just noticed this page as described above, but it I want to highlight it if anyone else has the same issue:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_216-imageresize.html